# How to append query string arguments to hyperlink URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a fully working jQuery code to select a URL matching a specified domain:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('a').each(function() {

        var href = $(this).attr('href');


        if(this.hostname && this.hostname == 'example.com') 
        {                   
            $(this)
                .removeAttr('target')
                .attr('rel', 'nofollow')                
                .attr('title', href)
       }
    });
});
```

As you can see, it will remove the target attribute, add rel nofollow and set title to the URL value. Now I having issue on how to modify the above code to add another feature to append query string to the URL value (href value). Supposing I want to append the following query string arguments/values:

```
argument1='test1'
argument2='test2'
```

such that the final URL will look like:

```
http://example.com/?argument1=test1&argument2=test2
```

Or any page of the example domain like

```
http://example.com/any_page/?argument1=test1&argument2=test2
```

Is there a simple method on doing this without using jQuery plugins?

Comment: Adding a nofollow in scripting won't really do what you want. Google et al run some JS, but not much, and your nofollow will likely not be honored. Best just to do this work server-side.

Comment: Thanks Clint, OK I get that. But any ideas how to add the query string arguments to the selected hyperlink URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for Objects and Arrays

or [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for form data

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DqXYn/